# Dynamics CRM: HTTPS SSL

Tags: https, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a web server hosting the Dynamics CRM 2013.

In IIS (8.5) there is other website with forms authentication. I want to use HTTPS for my web site (not for CRM Dynamics). For binding on **port 8081** it works fine, but for binding on **port 443**, "Windows Secure" appears and it requests Windows authentication. Why? Dynamics CRM has no binding for **443 port**, but trace log shows it tries to handle request for that port.

Answer (score 2):

433 is the default port, but this can be reconfigured, perhaps you have missed a step here. Check out the instructions here [Network ports for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM web application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699823.aspx#BKMK_NetworkPortsCRM).

> **TCP 443 HTTPS**
>
> Default secure HTTP port. The port number may differ from the default
> port. This secure network transport must be manually configured.
> Although this port is not required to run Microsoft Dynamics CRM, we
> strongly recommend it. For information about how to configure HTTPS
> for CRM, see “Make Microsoft Dynamics CRM client-to-server network
> communications more secure” in Post-installation and configuration
> guidelines for Microsoft Dynamics CRM in the Installing Guide.